# get prices with quantity of a product in controller in shopware 6

Tags: rules, shopware6

After setting the advanced prices of a product concerning rules on the admin side as shown in below pic.

[image: Set advanced prices for produc]
Now I want to get these prices with quantity in the controller.
I wrote the following code but it just shows one price.

```
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addAssociation('media');
        $criteria->addAssociation('prices');
        
        $productDatas = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context);
        foreach($productDatas->getEntities()->getElements() as $allData):
            $price = $allData->getPrice();
        endforeach;
```

Your help will be appreciated for.

Comment: Always provide your code, if possible, please.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get your product data from the `SalesChannelRepository` instead of the `EntityRepository`.

The argument for the service would be

```xml
<argument type="service" id="sales_channel.product.repository"/>
```

After that, you get your product data as you normally would and get the advanced prices from the `getCalculatedPrices` method.

```php
$product = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context)->first();
$advancedPrices = $product->getCalculatedPrices();
```

Comment: it shows the following error.

"Controller::__construct(): Argument #1 ($productRepository) must be of type Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface, Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Entity\SalesChannelRepository given"

Comment: The typehinting in your class is wrong, it needs to be changed to SalesChannelRepository aswell.